# Stop a specific liquid tag from being rendered

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am using a Twitter Feed Plugin in my Jekyll website, that also work with Liquid. It works well but every single time Jekyll renders the page, the liquid tag from that script gets rendered too, forcing me to re-write it again manually in the generated HTML otherwise it won’t work.

Is there any way I can stop a specific liquid tag from being rendered by Jekyll?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could wrap the tag inside a `{% raw %} ... {% endraw %}` block. This will prevent any liquid tag contained in this block from being processed by jekyll.